# Filtering all files from a folder and it's subfolders in java using FilenameFilter

Tags: java, filter

I want to lsit all the files form a directory i get as a paramter that end in .java and have a certain text in them,I have issues when i want to do this for all of it's ssubfolders.

Using filenamefilter on a folder only returns the files in the folder not in it's subfolders.

Any ideea how I can make it work on the subfolders too?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem and I am attaching my solution jsut in case somebody else bumps into this.Also,I used Threads because I found it easier to do it with Threads.

The ideea behind my solution was

1. one thread was in charge of getting all the files that end in ".java" [producer]
2. another parsing through those files to get the ones that contain a specific text

The Producer:

```
    public class ThreadProducator extends Thread {
       public Bufferino buffer ;
       File directory ;
       static ArrayList<File>files = new ArrayList<File>();
       public ThreadProducator(Bufferino a){
       this.buffer = a;
       directory = new File("src");
     }

    public static ArrayList<File> getFiles(File f){
        ArrayList<File> files1= new ArrayList<File>();
        for ( File fis : f.listFiles()){
         if ( fis.isDirectory()){
            getFiles(fis);
          }
         else{
            if(fis.getName().endsWith(".java")){
                files.add(fis);
                //System.out.println(files.toString());


            }
        }
       }
      return files;
     }

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(directory.isDirectory()){

        ArrayList<File>files =new ThreadProducator(buffer).getFiles(directory);
    //  System.out.println(files.toString());

        buffer.put(files);

        try {
            sleep((int)Math.random()*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
    }

   }
```

The Consumer:

```
   public class ThreadConsumator implements Runnable {
     private Bufferino buf;
     String lookedFor = "asdas";

     public ThreadConsumator(Bufferino bufi){
        this.buf = bufi;
     }


     @Override
     public void run() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          ArrayList<File> res = new ArrayList<File>();
          String content="";
          System.out.println("Files containing the word "+lookedFor+" are:");
          for ( int i = 0 ; i <25;i++){
            res = buf.get();
            for (File f : res)
              try {
                content = new Scanner(f).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

                 if(content.contains(lookedFor)){

                     System.out.println(f.getName());

                }

               /*System.out.println("-----------------------");
               System.out.println(content);
               System.out.println("-----------------------");*/
             }
             catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
           } 
        }

     }
```